# Retrolambda - Jack is required to support java 8 - warning fix

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, retrolambda

Is there a way to disable warning about

> Jack is required to support java 8 language features.

while using Retrolambda?

I don't want jack support for now since it doesn't yet compile our project.

Comment: it's not a warning, it's just an information. so why bother turning it off?

Comment: Don't you just love when things are clean? Actually it looks awful in jenkins, because there are like 30 lines of it.
I know it's not that big a deal, but if it's quick fix why not to bother?

Comment: 30 lines? that's interesting, I've got "only" 8 of them. anyways. no, I really don't care about these things. (If it was a real warning that would be different)

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Sadly I could not:(

Answer (score 14):

**android studio**

Add below codes in your application gradle after that do synck

```
// ----- add
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.4'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
// ----- end

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda' // ----- add 

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

//----add
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

You can just remove the following configuration from your `build.gradle` file:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

The `retrolambda` plugin will take care of this anyway and setup the Java compiler task with the correct source and target compatibility settings.

Comment: nope, that won't get rid of the messages (and it's afaik a must to add these lines if you use retrolambda)

Comment: Well, have you actually tried it? Looking at the source code of the retrolambda plugin shows me that it does exactly as I described, and I just tested that the Jack warning goes away if the compatibility settings are not set to VERSION_1_8.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I know that I've got those lines in my `build.gradle` and I still get the info - maybe I need an update of retrolambda, then.

Comment: Tested it with android gradle plugin version 2.1.0, buildToolsVersion 24, retrolamba plugin 3.2.5 and 3.3.0-beta4 (latest) and the info message is gone.

Comment: I've tried that, and now Android Studio says that language level is incompatible with lambda expression, and fix adds those lines back to build.gradle:) You didn't have this issue?

Comment: Ah I tested only on the command line with gradle. It's a pity Android Studio complains about, then I guess you don't have a choice.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm it is safe to remove VERSION_1_8 reference in build.gradle.
Furthermore if one set jack support to true at the same time at setting JAVA Version to 1.8 and using [Retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda), the following error kicks in:

[java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108471/java-lang-nullpointerexception-no-error-message-apk-building)

Answer (score -1):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.github.rxandroid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true

        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.2.0'

}
```

Comment: You should not be using this
`jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }`
Jack project was closed, when Android Studio 3.0 get's to stable channel you can remove retrolambda from project as this is already working perfectly there!