# java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message) APK building

Tags: java, android, gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The :app file

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.univpm.gruppoids.iotforemergencyandnavigation"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:1.0.0'
}
```

When i try to build APK it shows me: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Is it a problem with versions? or with lamdas?? someone can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue after adding:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

It was because my default java version was 10:

```
$ java -version
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
```

After changing to 1.8 (with **sudo update-alternatives --config java**) issue was fixed.

Comment: Downgrading the Java on my machine from Java 10 to Java 8 also fixed this problem.  But I downgraded by uninstalling Java 10 by following https://www.howtogeek.com/230145/how-to-uninstall-java-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thanks, lol after 3 hours installing, uninstalling stuff it should be done this simple move ;D

Comment: That's really oddly in my Android Studio, everything is normal when I using gradle tool build tasks, and in terminal `./gradlew build` will output: NullPointerException(no messages), no any key logs. My macOS Java version: java 12.0.1 2019-04-16, after I removed `compileOptions` block anything is be ok.

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same kind of problem these days. I found it might be caused by the version of gradle. After changing the version to 2.1.0, the problem's gone.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
```

I'm not sure it works for you.

Comment: After changing the version from 2.2.0 to 2.1.0 it shows me
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/org.jgrapht/jgrapht-ext/pom.xml
 File1: C:\Users\Piero\AndroidStudioProjects\IoTforEmergencyandNavigation\app\lib\jgrapht-ext-1.0.0.jar
 File2: C:\Users\Piero\AndroidStudioProjects\IoTforEmergencyandNavigation\app\lib\jgrapht-ext-1.0.0-uber.jar

Comment: This helped me I thank you so much :), I have been trying for 3 days to configure OpenCV with Android Studio. This is the only thing that worked for me thank you so much I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Where does this go?

Comment: In answer to the question that @gaharrington asked, this `classpath` line is part of the top-level build.gradle file.  However, gradle 2.1.0 is really old by now, so this solution is probably not helpful for most people anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your app module's **build.gradle** file:

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see [this other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223882/retrolambda-jack-is-required-to-support-java-8-warning-fix/41187936#41187936) : while this is stated in Retrolambda documentation you should not specify JAVA version to 1.8 while using Retrolambda. Therefore setting jack support to true should not be required anymore. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Android compiles by default with Java 7 but your project might be using some Java 8 features. If you recently switched from Oracle JDK to Open JDK, make sure you are using Java 8.
In your terminal, if you run `java -version`, the output should be something like:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_222-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score -6):

Just Delete your project under contains .gradle folder and restart android studio.
it tested by and approve by google developer pages.
It 100% working.

Comment: Could you link the source you're mentioning?